# What is AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android

I just came to know that AlertDialog.Builder is a class in Android.BUt according to naming conventions java class cannot have "." operator.So, I was just confused ....can anyone help me out?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: Static classes are referenced using `.`(dot) operator.

Answer (score 1):

`AlertDialog.Builder` is [a static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class) inside of `AlertDialog`.